# Access Array of Array in Pl SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have Array list having List of Arrays.

for example:

```
//Array list type is varchar
Listarray1(0) := 'data';
Listarray1(1) := 'data1';
Listarray2(0) := 'data2';
Listarray2(1) := 'data3';

//Sub list type is listarray
SUBLIST(0) := Listarray1;
SUBLIST(0) := Listarray2;
```

how to print the each array using loop

Answer (score 0):

Multidimensional arrays in PL/SQL you do like this:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE Sub_Array_list IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100);
    TYPE Array_list IS TABLE OF Sub_Array_list;
    My_array Array_list := Array_list();
BEGIN

    My_array.EXTEND;
    My_array(My_array.LAST) := Sub_Array_list('data', 'data1');
    My_array.EXTEND;
    My_array(My_array.LAST) := Sub_Array_list('data2', 'data3');

    FOR i IN My_array.FIRST..My_array.LAST LOOP
        FOR k IN My_array(i).FIRST..My_array(i).LAST LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'My_array('||i||')('||k||') = '||My_array(i)(k) );
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;

END;
```

Comment: Through this i can able to access one array in sublist but i have 26 array in that i am getting error ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection
ORA-06512: at line 42
06531. 00000 -  "Reference to uninitialized collection"

Comment: Most propably you forgot some `EXTEND`. Can you show your actual code?